# IBM MQMFT Agent exit files

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

What is the purpose of the exit files under folder `\IBM\WebSphereMQ\mqft\config\qmname\agents\agentname\exits`
These files are named `mail.jar` and `mftexit1.0.jar`

How does one enable them to work?

Comment: Review the IBM Knowledge center page "[Customizing MFT with user exits](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/user_exits.htm)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the exit files is to extend your Managed File Transfer functionality by writing your own programs as user exit routines.

i.e. You can write programs to archive, rename and encrypt files.

The mftexit1.0.jar JAR file was probably written by someone in your organization, the mail.jar JAR file contains JavaMail APIs, the SMTP service provider, the POP3 service provider, and the IMAP service provider.

For more info check the links below :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/user_exits.htm
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaha/javamail.htm